# Find if the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^\alpha )}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find if the improper integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x^\alpha)}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$, $\alpha + \beta > 1$, $\beta < 1$ converges or diverges.

I'm having a hard time with this one, I can't see a clear way to solve this and can't think of another function to compare this with. I can imagine that that it might converge since $\sin(x^\alpha)$ is limited and $x^{\alpha + \beta}$ grows, but I'm having trouble making it formal

Comment: In the title you have written $(\sin(x))^\alpha$. In the body of the question on the other hand $\sin(x^\alpha)$ is given. Which one is it?

Comment: @humanStampedist Fixed it, so sorry

Comment: Note that $|\sin(x)|\le1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^\alpha)}{x^\alpha}=1$

Comment: Have you tried splitting the integral into two intervals like $(0,1]$ and $[1,+\infty)$ and checking the convergence in both?

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you some hints:
First of all, you have to examine two seperate integrals:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x^\alpha)}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$$
and
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x^\alpha)}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$$
because at $x=0$ the denominator vanishes! For $x$ near zero you should employ, that $\sin x$ behaves linearly near $x=0$, i.e. you have
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$
Furthermore you then need to calculate something like
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^\beta}dx,$$
which will work as a upper boundary of the integral.

For the case that the upper limit of the integral is $\infty$, you can employ $|\sin(x^\alpha)|\leq 1$ and that $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^{\alpha+\beta}}dx$ can be calculated directly.